# Bold text AND math

Tags: bold, boldmath

Say that I have a phrase that I want to embolden:

```
$A$ is $\sigma$-strongly monotone.
```

How do I embolden the whole thing with one command? I don't want to individually type `\textbf{}` and `\mathbf{}` for every inline math in a line. You can't just write `\textbf{\mathbf{etc. etc.}}`. This doesn't embolden the math.

Comment: Do you want your maths bold-italic or bold-roman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand\bolden[1]{{\boldmath\bfseries#1}}

\begin{document}

$A$ is $\sigma$-strongly monotone. \bolden{$A$ is $\sigma$-strongly monotone.}

\end{document}
```

[image]